# Show rows depending upon dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to create form but am stuck at a point being newbie to Javascript and Jquery. Below is the HTML I am using

What I am trying to achieve is that when user chooses 0 no rows is shown and if he chooses 1 as drop down option  the number 1 rows and if he chooses 2 as drop down option both number 1 and number 2 row shows and of chooses 3 row number 1,row number 2 and row number 3 shows and so on...

Can you please help me in coding Javasript or jquery for the same ?

```html
Number of siblings &nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="siblingnum">
  <option>select one</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">Number<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">Name<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">Birthdate<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">Class<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">Gender<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">Schoolname<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">1<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="name1"><br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="date1"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="class1"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="g1"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="sname1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">2<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="name2"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="date2"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="class2"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="g2"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="sname2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">3<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="name3"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="date3"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="class3"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="g3"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="sname3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">4<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="name4"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="date4"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="class4"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="g4"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="sname4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">5<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="name5"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="date5"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="class5"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="g5"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="sname5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">6<br></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="name6"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="date6"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="class6"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="g6"></td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;"><input name="sname6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't a code writing service. You are expected to show your attempts at solving the problem and people here help you fix that code.

Comment: What did you try so far? Your question is tagged javascript, but there's no javascript in your question

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. Right now your question is off topic since there is no actual effor or code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usin jQuery, just get the select value when you change selection and then hide the rows you dont need via foreach loop

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "select" ).change(function () {
        var val = $( "select" ).val();
        if (val != 'select one') {
            var tableRows = $("table tr");
            jQuery.each(tableRows, function(i ,tr) {
                if (i > val) {
                    $(tr).hide();
                } else {
                    $(tr).show();
                }
            })
        }
      }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your `tbody` in `thead` and `tbody` to make it less complicated. And then just use them in a `change` callback. With `filter` and `:lt` you can select elements by `index`. Should be pretty easy to understand.

```js
$("select").change(function() {
    var rows = $("tbody tr").hide();
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    if( $.isNumeric(value) ) {
        rows.filter(":lt(" + value + ")").show();
    }
});
```

```css
tbody tr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="siblingnum">
  <option>select one</option>
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>


<table style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="vertical-align: top;">Number
        <br>
      </th>
      <th style="vertical-align: top;">Name
        <br>
      </th>
      <th style="vertical-align: top;">Birthdate
        <br>
      </th>
      <th style="vertical-align: top;">Class
        <br>
      </th>
      <th style="vertical-align: top;">Gender
        <br>
      </th>
      <th style="vertical-align: top;">Schoolname
        <br>
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">1
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="name1">
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="date1">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="class1">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="g1">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="sname1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">2
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="name2">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="date2">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="class2">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="g2">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="sname2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">3
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="name3">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="date3">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="class3">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="g3">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="sname3">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">4
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="name4">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="date4">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="class4">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="g4">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="sname4">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">5
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="name5">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="date5">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="class5">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="g5">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="sname5">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">6
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="name6">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="date6">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="class6">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="g6">
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <input name="sname6">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Doesn't produce the expected behavior

Comment: It is now correcte @charlietfl please remove downvote! Thx for hint.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='siblingnum']").change(function() {
        $( "tr" ).show();
        var selectValue = eval($(this).val());  
        $( "tr:gt("+selectValue+")" ).hide();
    });
});
```